Do I need a new multimeter, mine seems to be reading double what the DC volts should be
I was measuring my car battery, which works fine, as a test and my multimeter read 26 volts. Not sure if I'm reading it wrong, or if it just likes to double volts to make me happy. It's a GMT-312 from GB Instruments.
I was using this as a calibration test because I have a couple deep cycle Marine batteries that have been sitting for about 1.5 years and wanted to make sure they will work...but if my multimeter is exaggerating my volts, I need to mentally compensate for it. Or take the batteries in to get checked, but who has time for that. lol.
I'm attaching a photo of my multimeter during the reading of my car battery.
Thanks for any input. 

that meter does not use the battery to measure voltage ... the battery is for measuring resistance

what reading does it show when unconnected? ... what does it show when set to the other voltage ranges?

If it reads zero when disconnected, try cranking the selector switch back and forth around the 50V setting a bunch of times, sometimes they get flaky with disuse and/or corrosion.

Is your car running when measuring the battery voltage? Can you measure the voltage of a 9 V PP3 type battery?  Do you have two that you can connect in series to measure 18 V?

jsotola, it goes to zero when I'm not touching the battery. It also doubled the volts when reading double A or 9 volt batteries as well.  So, D Duck, my 9 volt battery measured 18 volts (roughly).  I'll try cranking the selector switch a few times and see what happen. Might just buy another one or borrow a friends. Thanks for the input!

what about the other ranges, such as the 150 V range?

jsotola, when I turn it to 150, the batteries don't show up on the needle.  I'll be borrowing a different multimeter later this week from a friend.  Should have some answers then.
